# jquery ajax call put data

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

```js
$.ajax({

type: "PUT",
url: url,
data: data,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
  alert("success");


},
error: function(data) {
  var errors = data.responseJSON;
  console.log(errors);
}

})
});
```

the success event get triggered even though the post call fails (validation error), when does the error function get called?. what did i do wrong in that?

Comment: try changing `url: 'url,` to `url:url,` . Hope this will help.

Comment: try to send response status with `status: :unprocessable_entity` when error occurs

Comment: @SushantPimple that's a typo here. i have edited now

Comment: Your are sending errors with status code 200. Thats why jquery treats it as success. send validation errors with status code 400 or something

Comment: @Vishal thank u . that's what the mistake is

Comment: Can i post it as answer, will you upvote it ?

Comment: yes please post

Comment: I posted answer please accept and upvote it, so it will help other user to resolve this issue in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when validation fails you need to send response status with `status: :unprocessable_entity` so it will go in error event in ajax call

Answer (score 0):

The required parameters in an Ajax error function are jqXHR, exception, use it like below :

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
  });
```